# How to get difference between two datetime of moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I calculate the difference between two dates time in moment.js?

```
moment.duration((moment(startDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a")).diff(moment(new Date()).format("MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a")));

and My startDate = 2022-02-02T12:12:25Z
```

Comment: Why do you format before calculating the difference? Formatting returns a string. You can’t calculate a date difference between strings.

Comment: It's possible to use  date like this 2022-02-02T12:12:25Z to calculate the difference.

Comment: My problem  is the format of my startDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ,may help other people  :

```
var now = moment(new Date(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var then = moment(new Date(startDate), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var diffTime = moment.duration(then.diff(now));   
and it depends  to you how you want to get difference in seconds ,minutes  or hours :
diffTime.asHours();
```

Comment: There is no need to add the `"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"` format, you can use directly `new Date('2022-02-02T12:12:25Z')`.

Comment: Yes you are right